# Swift Coredata change notification: NSDeletedObjectsKey found nil value

Tags: swift

Upon NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification handling

```
let changes: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
let deletedObjects:NSSet = changes.valueForKey(NSDeletedObjectsKey) as! NSSet
```

Crash :unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping

while its working fine in objc

Answer (score 0):

Replace `as!` with `as?` for the optional unwrapping. Forced unwrapping with the exclamation mark will always crash when trying to unwrap a nil.

Comment: value of optional type NSSet not unwrapped
To Fixit - insert “()!”

so its same issue

Comment: let deletedObjects:NSSet = changes.valueForKey(NSDeletedObjectsKey) as? NSSet ?? NSSet()